# Maven copy dependent jars into the war lib

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war

I have a maven project with 3 modules inside. Two projects that produces jar on build, and a project that builds a WAR file. The produced WAR file has all the dependency jars copied into its `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Whereas the libraries that the other projects uses are not included. How do I configure the maven project to copy other jar files into the WAR?

The parent pom.xml

```
  <project>
    <....>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>project-service</module>
        <module>project-api</module>
        <module>project-platform</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
  </project>
```

The web project pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>company.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>company.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you dont. maven usually does this automatically - any transitive dependencies are copied as well. Do you refer to dependencies in project-service and project-api? can you post one of those pom.xml files as well? Do you have a module using packaging "war" that builds the war file?

Comment: Unless those dependencies are scoped such that they are excluded from being transitive dependencies of course, such as "provided".

Comment: I don't quite understand here ... which one is your WAR project, what's its name? I'm guessing it's project-platform? So you expect project-platform.war to include project-api.jar and project-service.jar in WEB-INF/lib and they're not there? Can you confirm I understand you correctly?

Comment: wemu, yeah, the maven does it automagically. dcsohl, you are right. I found the problem. The problem was due to a plug-in I added to manually to add all the library jars into the WAR, and that filtered-out the other library jars used by other dependent projects. Thank you all for your helps.